# Prevent of--screen content from resizing the page on mobile safari

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile-safari

I'm currently in the process of creating a mobile navigation menu for a responsive website.

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf3IH.png

When the user clicks the little arrows, the whole thing moves 100vw to the left. The parts the user isn't supposed to see are supposed to be off screen, but as you can see, mobile Safari resizes the page to show them.

How can I solve this?

EDIT: Forgot to add the code, sorry about that, here goes:

```
#sitenav, #sitenav ul{
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 100vw;
                    background-color: white;
                    border: black solid 1px;
                    top: 80px;
                    left: 0;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    list-style: none;
                    overflow: visible;
                    background-color: #FCF9F0;
                }

                #sitenav ul {
                    left: 100vw;
                    top: 0;
                }
```

The HTML is written as:

```
<ul class='navbar-dropdown' id="sitenav">
                        <li>
                            <a href=''>Verblijven</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Huizen of chalets</li>
                                <li>Het indiaans dorp</li>
                                <li>Het gallisch dorp</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>Activiteiten
                            <ul>
                                <li>Afdeling "River"
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Kayak / Kano</li>
                                        <li>Rafting</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
etc...
```

SECOND EDIT:

The problem appears to be solved by wrapping the whole thing in a div with these CSS rules:

```
div.clip-abs {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position:absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This feels a bit hackish, and it ignores the concept of separating data and style. Since the page is responsive, I now have a div that is useless for desktop users. Is this the only way?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this in <head> tag: 
 `<meta name="viewport"
content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=0">` 
set #sitenav position relative

Comment: Sorry, I already tried that, I'm afraid. I'll add the CSS of the navigation menu, they are absolutely positioned.

Comment: set #sitenav position relative